# How to become a child in the Minecraft Comes Alive mod?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, minecraft-comes-alive

Is there a way that you can be a child and not be a parent? Like having parents of your own, and you being a child.

Comment: Removed mod suggestion. Now it's an op-topic question.

Answer (score -1):

No. you can not do that unfortunately. there are other mods to become a child and/or have parents. you can mix certain mods.